# Using react-datepicker with redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, momentjs, redux-form

I am trying to use the react-datepicker with redux-form and I am facing an issue. When I select a date from the date picker I get the following error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.isSame is not a function
```

My code is the following :

```
// My component that uses the date picker
const renderDateField = (field) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={require('./images/date.png')} className={styles.iconField} />
      <DatePicker {...field.input} placeholderText={field.placeholder} onChange={field.onDateChange} dateFormat='DD/MM/YYYY' selected={field.selected ? field.selected : null} className={styles.inputField} />
    </div>
  );
};

export class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startDate: moment()
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange (date) {
    console.log('handle Change', date);
    this.setState({
      startDate: date.format('DD/MM/YYYY')
    });
  }

  render () {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    console.log('Render global state.startDate', this.state.startDate);
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.props.filterSubmit)} method='post' action='/tennis/search'>
                ...
                <Field name='date' placeholder='Quand ?' component={renderDateField} onDateChange={this.handleChange} selected={this.state.startDate} />
                ...
        </form>
      </div>)
    ;
  }
}
...
TennisSearchFilters.propTypes = {
  filters: React.PropTypes.shape({
    date: React.PropTypes.object
  }),
  filterSubmit: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  handleSubmit: propTypes.handleSubmit
};
    ...
export default reduxForm({
          form: 'tennisSearch',
          validate: validateTennisSearchForm
        })(TennisSearchFilters);
```

I think that there is a format error as the input value seems to be updated to a string and then it crashes when comparing a moment to a string. But I am not quite sure of it... therefore I request for your help :)

I checked others posts and questions about it but it did not work properly (maybe I did something wrong however).

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code sample provided, I assume `react-datepicker` is using `moment` under the hood.

`onChange` method receives `moment` instance and you are converting this instance to plain string. Then, `react-datepicker` tries to invoke `isSame` method on string value, which of course will fail.

Instead of converting updated value to string, store is as received.

```
this.setState({
    startDate: date,
});
```

Comment: Just as simple as that. I was pretty sure that I have tested it before but anyway this solve my problem. I am quite a beginner and I still need to understand properly what is passed to each function and when :)

Comment: Thanks a lot again ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try in your calendar component::

```
 onChange ={val => {
   field.onDateChange // Rather read the value from redux-form
   return field.input.onChange(val) // This should dispatch the value to redux-form
  }
}
```

Not sure why you're setting an additional view state here when using redux-form?

Comment: Yes, overriding the `onChange` that is already in `field.input` is a mistake.

Comment: As I assume it to be an internal component state, I don't want it to be part of my form validation. This is why I wanted ti be out of the redux store :)

Comment: I guess when the guy who wrote redux-form thinks its not a good idea, its not a good idea :)

Comment: Also if thats the case, just dont include it in your validation.